# SAS SQL where clause on alias failing

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to subset the data using a where clause as below:

```
proc sql outobs=100;
create table Dbtr_Clnt_Generl_Inf as
  select FACS_Schema_ID '',
        'DBACCT*'n as ACCOUNT_NUM '',
        input(DBLSTDTI,yymmdd10.) as Date_Listed format=date09.
  from sqlsrv10.Acct_Dbtr_Clnt_Generl_Inf
  where Date_Listed >= '01Sep2016'd
  ;
quit;
```

But I am getting an error: ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: Date_Listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PROC SQL you need to use the CALCULATED keyword when referencing a derived variable.

```
where calculated Date_Listed >= '01Sep2016'd
```

Or just reference the original variable instead of the derived one

```
where DBLSTDTI='2016-09-01'
```

Comment: It takes a long time to process 100 observations.  I cancelled the query.

Comment: Are you pulling from a database? Then you need to use a format so that the WHERE clause can be processed by the database. Try DBLSTDTI='2016-09-01'.  Or use an explicit pass thru query.

Comment: But since it's a string I can only equate to a string but not use greater than (>) a certain date.  I have a LIBNAME connection to my database.  DBLSTDTI is stored as a date in the SQL Server database but the LIBNAME connection sqlsrv10 to the table Acct_Dbtr_Clnt_Generl_Inf is saying it is a text field when I look at properties.

Comment: This is my LIBNAME connection: LIBNAME sqlsrv10 oledb init_string="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
Persist Security Info=true;
Initial Catalog=mydbo;
Data Source=myserver";

Comment: One of the nice things about using a string in YYMMDD format is you CAN use inequalities to test the values.

Comment: Try using `CONNECT USING sqlsrv10 ; select input(DBLSTDTI,yymmdd10.) as SASDATE format=YYMMDD10. from connection to sqlsrv10 (select DBLSTDTI where DBLSTDTI = DATE '2016-09-01') ;`